# how to optimize CSG Library by decreasing the resolution or the size or number of BSP trees?

Tags: javascript, three.js, boolean-operations, threecsg

I am trying to perform a boolean operation on 2 mesh files imported from objloader using THREE.js and ThreeCSG interactively for multiple times and in real time. I just wanted to ask if there is any ways to optimize the CSG code to decrease the run time of the boolean operation by decreasing the resolution ([link](https://risacher.org/OpenJsCad/index.html)) or the number or size of the BSP trees to make the program run real time or faster? the objects I am using are pretty big so this is one of the reasons its running slowly.
Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can tinker with `CSG.Plane.EPSILON` parameter if you increase it the CSG operation should be faster, but more crude

Comment: I tried to increase the number from 1e-5 to 1e+20 but it did not change in terms of running time. How big can I increase it as it is the tolerance to check whether the point is on the plane. And is there any other parameters that can help to accelerate the boolean operation ?

Comment: use just small decrements :)  from 1e-5 to 1e-3, etc.  I used ".1" and it became noticeably faster.  I will revert back to 1e-5 when exporting the model, because the smaller the Epsilon, the higher the quality.